# Is there a way to display numerical values in a foreach loop as "Min - Max"?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF post object field to display multiple Woocommerce products as post type items. However, I'm trying to only display the prices of these selected products as a min/max price range (eg. $21.95 - $58.50).

Here is the code I'm using for the loop but it just shows every price. Is there a way to just show the lowest and highest price as a price range?

```
<?php
$linked_products = get_field('linked_products');
if( $linked_products ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $linked_products as $post ): 
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <?php $product = wc_get_product( $post ); $prices = $product->get_price_html(); echo $prices; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set php variables and store lowest and highest price in those variables

```
<?php
$linked_products = get_field('linked_products');

if( $linked_products ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $linked_products as $post ): 
        setup_postdata($post);
        if(!isset($lowest_price) || $product->get_price() < $lowest_price) {
          $lowest_price = $product->get_price();
        }
        if(!isset($highest_price) || $product->get_price() > $highest_price) {
          $highest_price = $product->get_price();
        }
        ?>
        <?php $product = wc_get_product( $post ); $prices = $product_price; echo $prices; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It displays the prices range as lowest price to highest price:

```
<?php
$linked_products = get_field('linked_products');
$lowest_price = 100000;
$highest_price = 0;
if( $linked_products ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $linked_products as $post ): 
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <?php 
            $product = wc_get_product( $post ); 
            $prices = $product->get_price_html(); 
            $prices = str_replace("$", "", $prices);
            if ($prices > $highest_price) $highest_prices = $prices
            else if ($prices < $lowest_price) $lowest_prices = $prices 
        ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php
       echo "$". $lowest_price . " - " . "$". $highest_price;
    ?>
<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```